# match mutiple and optional variables with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

Consider this **string**;

```
$str = "[1]a[2] a [2] a [3][3]";
```

I want to get a list of all the matches between the square brackets, which works fine. with `'\[(.*?)\]'` pattern. Additionally I want to match anything from the end of each square bracket match [*] to the next opening of a square bracket [ (i.e, the A's in between) ]

This **pattern**;

```
$pattern = '/\[(.*?)\](.*?(\[?)?)/i';
```

returns only the first matchs of square brackets and no As.

```
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {
  print_r($matches);
}
```

The **result;**

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] [1] => [2] [2] => [2] [3] => [3][ ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) [3] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [ ) )`

What I am trying to achieve is to rebuild the string to wrap anything between square brackets in  tags. So the string `"123 [1]a[2] a [2] a [3][3] bar"` I want to be rebuilt to `"123 <a>[1]</a>a<a>[2]</a> etc.."`

I am looping the matches to rebuild the string.

```
  $value = '<sup>a [1] wef [2] r4f [we] we</sup>';

    $re = '/\<sup\>(.*?)\<\/sup\>/'; 
      

    $value = preg_replace_callback(
     $re,
     function($m) {
        $new_links = "";
        if(preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]((.*)\[?)/i', $m[0], $matches)) {
          foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
              $new_links .='[<a class="note_href"  href="note'.$match[0].'" target="_self">'.$match[0].'</a>]'.$match[1];
          }
        }                 
        $subst = '<sup>'.$new_links.'</sup>';  
        return $subst;
      },
      $value);
```

**Optimal way, Thanks to @Thefourthbird;**

```
  $re =   '/\[([^][]+)]/';
  $value = preg_replace($re, '<a class="note_href"  href="note$1" target="_self">$1</a>', $value);
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Like this? `\[[^][]*]|[^][\s]+` https://regex101.com/r/HMua55/1 See https://3v4l.org/do92H

Comment: @anubhava I'm trying to turn anything inside square brackets into an html href

Comment: @1000iq Are there only digits between the square brackets?

Comment: @1000iq: Please add expected result for `$str = "123 [1]a[2] a [2] a [3][3] bar";` to your question.

Comment: @anubhava there can be anything between the square brackets. I want to rebuild it into a string where "123 [1]a[2] a [2] a [3][3] bar" would be "123<a>[1]</a> etc.."

Comment: @1000iq So like this? https://regex101.com/r/GutoxO/1 Then second `[3]` in `[3][3]` would not be part of the replacement then?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I would want anything between square brackets to be in tags. regex101.com/r/GutoxO/1 is missing the first occurrence too. I added the code I'm using to loop through matches to rebuild it. Is this optimal? the href of the a has to have what's between the brackets. Sorry, this is getting confusing now

Comment: @1000iq The confusing part is that you use different data examples each time. There is `[1]a[2] a [2] a [3][3]` and there is `123 [1]a[2] a [2] a [3][3] bar` and there is `a [1] wef [2] r4f [we] we` Can you add to the question what the exact replacements should be for each of the example strings?

Comment: @Thefourthbird The reason is because it will always be different because it will be from user input. The user can add anything to the <sup> tags. I want to find all the square bracket instances and wrap them in <a> tags so i can anchor them to the citations at the bottom of the page

Comment: @1000iq But with such mixed data, you could match `\[[^][]+]` and replace with `<a>$0</a>` Why do you want to match the data not between square brackets?

Comment: @Thefourthbird You are 100% right. I added the answer to the end of the post. I'm not sure why I over complicated it. Thank you so much! Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep to up-vote your comments.

Answer (score 1):

As you already capture the content between the right tags, for the different example strings in between, you can omit the capture group and use a negated character class to match from `[...]`

Then in the replacement, wrap the full match between `<a>$0</a>`

The pattern would look like:

```
\[[^][]+]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added parenthesis \[([^][]+)] and used $1, to thwart the [] so I could use the contents of the iteration to the <a> href